# unable to create mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

here i'm going to create basic mysql table but have a problem.

> > Error is : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME varchar(100) )' at line 3

```
CREATE TABLE `AB_CATEGORY`
(
ID integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
NAME varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: `IDENTITY` isn't a valid part of the query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the IDENTITY  keyword-

```
CREATE TABLE `AB_CATEGORY`
(
   ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   NAME varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: Maybe add `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: I think There will no problem just in creating a table without AUTO_INCREMENT . anyway thanks to make out the point@tadman.

Comment: There's no problem without it, but it's usually best to have it turned on by default since manually assigning ID values is really annoying and it's the best interpretation of what `IDENTITY` means in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

In your query to create a table, you are using MS SQL version of auto increment which is `IDENTITY`. Use this query instead:

```
CREATE TABLE `AB_CATEGORY`
(
ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME varchar(100)
);
```

Check out auto incrementing [documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)